# How to use BEGIN TRANSACTION with while loop in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

How to use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` with while loop in SQL Server?

This query never finishes perhaps because it stops and look for `COMMIT TRANSACTION` after inserting one row (when `@cnt = 1`) but I don't want to `COMMIT TRANSACTION` because I want to see results before committing.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
  DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

  WHILE @cnt <= 100
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @offset INT = 1

      INSERT INTO totalSales (col1, col2)
          SELECT 
              'Col1', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2) + @offset 
          FROM
              sales

      SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
  END;
```

So how I can check result before commit in while loop?

Comment: Do you want to see it in the same batch or outside the batch?

Comment: I want to see result before commit in same batch

Comment: @shaadi what is the use of while loop here?

Comment: Your loop works fine, it runs 100 times, you are going to be inserting 100 * however many records are in that sales table using this loop.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a `BEGIN TRAN` outer (general), and inside loop while create a `BEGIN TRAN inner` (with a trans name).
Inside loop, if are conditions to rollbacks only for this iteration i use `SAVE TRAN` savepoint for not lose previous trans.

I 've created an example tests in loop while with conditional inserts and rollback savepoint:

```
declare @num int
set @num = 0

--drop table #test
create table #test (
    valor Varchar(100)
)
begin tran
while @num <= 5
begin
    begin transaction tran_inner
    insert into #test (valor) values ('INSERT 1 INNER -> ' + convert(varchar(10),@num))
    save transaction sv_inner
        insert into #test (valor) values ('INSERT 2 EVEN - SAVEPOINT -> ' + convert(varchar(10),@num))
        if @num % 2 = 0 begin
            commit transaction sv_inner
        end else begin
            rollback transaction sv_inner
        end
    insert into #test (valor) values ('INSERT 3 INNER -> ' + convert(varchar(10),@num))
    set @num = @num + 1
    if @@trancount > 0 begin 
        commit transaction tran_inner
    end
end
select valor from #test;
if @@trancount > 0 begin 
    commit tran
end
```

Return rows: 1, 2 if iteration even, and 3.

[image: img returns tsql]

Answer (score 1):

In the same batch (within the same transaction) you can simply issue a `SELECT` command to see the updated content of the table. Changes will be persisted when the `COMMIT TRANSACTION` statement is executed or reverted on `ROLLBACK`.

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), x VARCHAR(32));
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO test (x) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO test (x) VALUES ('b');

SELECT * FROM test;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4910/2

Alternatively you can use the `INSERT INTO .. OUTPUT` construct to output the result of the `INSERT` statement.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

Outside the batch (using a second connection), you can use `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level to be able to read records not committed yet.

Docs: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I am incrementing field ( + @offset ) therefore using the loop to find col2 value your solution isn't working in my case.

Comment: I want to see complete result of while loop before commiting

Comment: Local variables are not part of a transaction, therefore it's value is not affected. You can always issue a `SELECT` after the loop but before committing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying it never finishes it sounds to me like you are getting some blocking going on because that loop runs just fine.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2429/how-to-identify-blocking-in-sql-server/

I HIGHLY recommend using Adam Machanic's sp_WhoIsActive for this as well: http://whoisactive.com

Comment: Before I download his SP, could you tell me if I need Admin privilege to execute this SP?

Comment: You need to have VIEW SERVER STATE permissions.  He lays it all out in this doc: http://whoisactive.com/docs/04_installation/